# How to select vertically in textedit using keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, textedit

How do i select vertically (columnar) in TextEdit using keyboard?

I can do that using mouse i.e. pressing the option button and selecting the text but I would like to do the same with keyboard.

How do I do that?

Comment: +1 for teaching me that I can do it with the mouse!

Comment: Keyboard Maestro? or several other keyboard macro programs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with that is that the Mac's modifier keys <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> are used in conjunction with the arrow keys to navigate through text more quickly by going to the beginning or end of a line or the beginning or end of the next/previous word, respectively.

There may be a utility that will allow you to modify the system-wide defaults but you run the risk of breaking text editing *everywhere* in the system.

Comment: yeah. I dont want to modify system-wide settings. I was more curious about if there are any in-build textedit commands i can use.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I'll add here . . . Regarding @Steve Chambers and @Asdfg respective [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322214/how-to-select-vertically-in-textedit-using-keyboard#322217) and comment, there is a checkbox in TextEdit Preferences that allow you to turn off "smart" copy paste.